# Родительный или винительный падеж после "слушаться"?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, управление, родительный-или-винительный

Детям положено слушаться: учителя в школе, воспитателя в  детском саду, а еще,  конечно, маму и папу. Или мамы и папы? Но так не говорят.

Какой здесь используется падеж и почему?

Вот еще примеры:

(1) Если бы мы заставили внутренние органы слушаться наших команд, мы бы продлили себе жизнь. 
(2) Хрущев успел уже распорядиться ― команд от Кастро не исполнять, слушаться только Москвы.

А это какой падеж?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С этими падежами интересно! Как плавно помета "разг." при винительном переходит в "устар."!..

Вначале общее - о двояком управлении:

> Многие слова допускают двоякое управление зависимым существительным,
>   но допустимые варианты при этом различаются оттенками значения.
>   Например, глагол ждать может присоединять существительное,
>   обозначающее объект ожидания, как в родительном, так и в винительном
>   падеже. Если мы используем вариант жду автобуса (род. п.), то
>   подчеркиваем неопределенность: какого-нибудь, любого автобуса; если же
>   говорим жду поезд Москва – Ярославль (вин. п.), то подчеркиваем как
>   раз определенность (никакой другой поезд нас не интересует). Слово
>   жаль (жалко) управляет винительным падежом (жалеть кого-что), когда
>   подразумевается чувство сострадания по отношению к кому-либо или
>   чему-либо (жаль девочку, жалко увядшую гвоздику), и родительным
>   падежом (жалеть кого-чего), когда выражается чувство грусти, сожаления
>   по поводу отсутствия, утраты кого-либо или чего-либо (жаль времени,
>   жаль прошлого). Глагол отвезти управляет винительным падежом (отвезти
>   кого-что), если подразумевается полный охват предмета действием
>   (отвезите ей дрова – имеются в виду все дрова), и родительным падежом
>   (отвезти кого-чего), когда подразумевается частичный охват предмета
>   действием (отвезите ей дров – имеется в виду какая-то часть дров).
>   Подобные оттенки следует учитывать, обращаясь в затруднительных
>   случаях к справочной литературе.

Но здесь нет искомого глагола "слушаться"; ищем-с...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, падежи уравнены в правах; а далее - и помета "устар." обнаруживается:

[**§ 1765.**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1749-1772.html#1765)

> В варьировании беспредложных падежей центральное место занимает мена
>   род. и вин. п. Здесь, в зависимости от глагола, разграничиваются
>   следующие случаи.
>
> При глаголах хотеть, желать, жаждать, ждать, просить, спрашивать
>   'просить', **слушаться**, заслуживать:
>
> заслуживать награду и награды (но при сов. виде только заслужить
>   награду); спрашивать совета, позволения и (разг.) совет, позволение;
>   **слушаться бабушку и (устар.) - бабушки; слушаться команды и (разг.) команду** (Гущин обязан во всем слушаться райкома, отчитываться перед
>   райкомом. Тендр.)...

Если верить источнику (а это АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР / ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА), то верно

> Если бы мы заставили внутренние органы слушаться наших команд, мы бы
>   продлили себе жизнь, -

родительный (думаю, падеж продиктован множественным числом и/или неодушевлённостью).

Второе предложение-пример

> Хрущев успел уже распорядиться ― команд от Кастро не исполнять,
>   слушаться только Москвы

подпадает под другое правило (и даже под два) - об управлении при глаголах с отрицанием и то же, но с инверсией.

> В и н и т е л ь н ы й    п  а  д  е  ж ([§ 201](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlv.html)),  ослабляющий значение отрицания,
>   обычно употребляется <...> при инверсии дополнения (постановке его
>   впереди глагола-сказуемого), например: Журнал я этот не люблю
>   (Тургенев); …Дверь не притворяла (Достоевский); Война торговлю не
>   разоряет (Горький); Трактор им не дали (Шолохов).

Я спокойно оставила бы "команд от Кастро", т. е. родительный, во избежание двусмысленности: винительный здесь исказил бы формальный признак - число.

Comment: Систематическое цитирование авторитетных авторов без указания источника - это подлог или плагиат?

Comment: Галина, спасибо за интересный и содержательный ответ, у меня по этой теме вот какие мысли:
1) Переходные глаголы могут управлять В .п. и Р.п., что определяется по смыслу: ждать поезд – ждать поезда.
2) Непереходные глаголы не могут управлять  В.п., поэтому у них выбора нет: только Р.п.
3) Глагол «слушаться» - непереходный, так как частица СЯ является показателем непереходности, однако он управляет В.п.: слушаться маму.

Comment: 4) Как оценить это явление? Может быть,  это явление синонимичности форм, например:  решить уехать – решиться уехать, стучать  в дверь – стучаться в дверь, по аналогии: слушать маму – слушаться маму.  Вот, кажется, в словаре есть ответ:   Слушать.  5. кого-что.  = Слушаться (1 зн.). С. родителей. С. врача.  Ребёнок никого не слушает. Совсем перестал с. старших.
5) Тогда понятно: НЕПЕРЕХОДНЫЙ ГЛАГОЛ УПОТРЕБЛЯЕТСЯ  ЗНАЧЕНИИ ПЕРЕХОДНОГО И ПОЭТОМУ МОЖЕТ УПРАВЛЯТЬ В.П.

Comment: Тогда получается, что глагол "слушаться"  всё-таки имеет возможность выбора В.п. или Р.п.: слушаться Москву/Москвы. В сочетании с дополнением команда/команды (неодуш.) используется Р.п. (как для непереходного глагола): слушаться команды/команд.

Comment: Сергей, судя по корпусной грамматике, глагол "слушаться" может быть переходным.[Б. Переходность и глагольная префиксация](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#). Прочитайте, думаю, вам будет интересно.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, я ознакомлюсь по возможности (материал достаточно объёмный, требует внимательного прочтения).

Answer (score 1):

> Детям положено слушаться: учителя в школе, воспитателя в детском саду, а еще, конечно, маму и папу. Или мамы и папы? Но так не говорят.

Говорят. Во всяком случае раньше вариант родительного был если не единственным, то главным. Сейчас здесь немного разные значения, при этом винительный более употребителен.

А вообще вопрос неинтересный и скучный. Это все из той же серии глаголов с двойным управлением. Тут нет различия по линии конкретного-обобщенного объекта, но есть акцентация на "маму" в варианте "слушайся мамы" и на "слушайся", если "маму".

Comment: Ну, это уже значительно лучше (я имею в виду форму, а не содержание), надеюсь, Вы на правильном пути. А если по сути, то мы, кажется, друг друга не слышим и не понимаем, поэтому нам  (для повышения качества ресурса) лучше воздержаться от совместных обсуждений и оценок. С уважением, Sergey, 20.02.2016.

Comment: Вот на это пойти никак не могу. Во-первых, это противоречит политике ресурса, свобода слова не может быть ограничена, во-вторых, Я на ресурсе больше четырех лет и все это время не жалел сил на то, чтобы делать ресурс лучше высказывая свое мнение по любому вопросу, где считаю себя компетентным.

Comment: Да я про себя говорю, а Вас ни к чему не обязываю. Единственное пожелание - это проявление свободы слова в достойной для этой свободы форме.

Comment: У нас слишком разные оценки достойного. Я считаю, что Ваше копания в форме моих комментариев выходит за рамки политики ресурса. Комментарии не для того, чтобы устраивать длительные дискуссии ни о чем. Это я Вам точно говорю, как человек неоднократно пострадавший на том, что дал втянуть себя в подобный обмен пустыми репликами. Для особо желающих есть чат. Все что пишется в ответах и комментариях здесь должно быть хоть сколько интересно большинству читающих, а не только пишушему.

Comment: Мы уже договорились, что я не читаю Ваших комментариев, поэтому любые дискуссии, краткие или длительные, отменяются. К Вам же одна просьба: по возможности избегайте негативной оценки отвечающих, оценивайте только их ответы.

Comment: Я с Вами ни о чем не договаривался.

Comment: @behemothus, а почему разные значения? Здесь смысловых различий вроде нету. Они есть с глаголами "ждать" и подобными. И то не всегда, только в случае множественного объекта.  "Жду лошадь" - "жду лошади".

Comment: @Morkovkin  Ну и тут тоже. Пусть будет лошадь. *Слушаться лошади* и *слушаться лошадь*. Вполне возможный оборот, кстати, у тренеров по выездке.  Я вижу тут различия в акцентах, не как в "жду трамвая/трамвай" а по части "именно слушайся [лошади] / [слушайся] именно лошадь". Но это сторонний вопрос, на обсуждение сейчас не выносится. Для меня важно, что сама возможность таких конструкций показывает иллюзорность догматического построения концепции переходности исключительно на свойстве управлять винительным падежом. В этом отношении "слушаться" ни чем не лучше "ждать".

Comment: Не Вы мне сами Зализняка  показывали с его концепцией ждательного падежа (правда, по другому поводу)?