# Слушаться - переходный глагол?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, глаголы, управление, родительный-или-винительный

Глагол "слушаться" - непереходный.
 **Но: слушаться маму** - В. п. без предлога и с "ся" на конце.
 Это исключение или нет? В учебнике про это ничего не сказано.

Comment: См. так же здесь: [Родительный или винительный?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422287/%d0%a0%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

Глагол "слушаться" относится к классу лабильных глаголов (глаголы,способные быть и переходными, и непереходными в разных употреблениях). Сюда также относятся:

1) глаголы, *бояться, дожидаться*, которые могут управлять **винительным падежом (бояться маму) наряду с родительным (бояться мамы):**

> ***Они боялись маму и потому не звонили, чтобы не причинять беспокойства [Л. Гурченко. Аплодисменты (1994-2003)].***
>
> **В доме я была работница: ставила самовар, топила печь, мела полы и должна была слушаться мать, мужа, брата, сестру  и не выходить из их воли [Ф. М. Решетников. Между людьми (1864)].**

2) некоторые дериваты с циркумфиксами: дождаться, заждаться, добудиться: Алешка, наверное, совсем заждался свою вечно занятую мамочку ("Аргументы и факты"). Жозе Моуринью съездил на Волгу и выучил два русских слова, Алан Дзагоев прошел, пробил и победил, а спартаковец Алекс дождался свою электричку (www.sports.ru).

> В полдень Бэду едва добудились два служителя, присланные нарочно Верховным Жрецом [Е. Хаецкая. Синие стрекозы Вавилона / Человек по имени Бэда (2004)].

См.: [Русская корпусная грамматика](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1749-1772.html#1765)

Answer (score 1):

Слушаться маму (В.п.) – это **исключение для возвратного глагола "слушаться".**

**Пояснение**

1) В русском языке существуют **два залога**: действительный (они строят дом) и страдательный (дом строится, дом построен).

2) Все глаголы с постфиксом СЯ, не имеющие страдательного значения, являются **возвратными** и относятся к действительному залогу (одеваться, обниматься, кусаться, радовться и др.).

3) **Почти все возвратные глаголы являются непереходными** (это связано с тем, что исходно само возвратное местоимение, к которому восходит постфикс СЯ, занимало позицию прямого дополнения).

4) **Исключения составляют следующие глаголы,** которые могут управлять винительным падежом (бояться маму) наряду с родительным (бояться мамы):

**а) слушаться, бояться, сторониться, стесняться и др.:**

**б) некоторые дериваты** (производные слова) с циркумфиксами: дождаться, заждаться, добудиться:

**в) хотеться** – единственный возвратный глагол с близким к пассивному значением, при котором исходное дополнение глагола хотеть (хочу яблоко/чаю) не продвигается в позицию подлежащего, а остаётся дополнением:

[Переходность | rusgram.ru](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 0):

> "Слушаться" - переходный глагол?

Строго говоря - нет.

*Но в рамках школьной программы - да, для простоты его и некоторые другие (опасаться, придерживаться и проч.) можно записать в переходные* и считать исключениями - в том смысле, что они управляют прямым дополнением, хотя и имеют все формальные признаки возвратности. Если не ошибаюсь, авторы учебников школьного уровня так и делают.

В академической грамматике и тем более общей лингвистике переходность определяется по-другому. В первой за основу берется способность глагола образовывать страдательные причастия (в русском языке это единственно, что оправдывает введение самого понятия переходности), общая же лингвистика берет за основу способность глагола прямо воздействовать, а дополнения "принимать", акцептировать действие глагола - для образования пассивных, например, конструкций.

Так вот, ни по одному их этих научно-академических определений глаголы рассматриваемой группы переходными не являются. Страдательных причастий они не образуют (это абсолютно невозможно для возвратных глаголов), акцептировать действие ни в каком виде тоже не могут ("мама слушаемшаяся сыном" - убийственно, "слушающаяся сыном" - абсурдно). То есть, с этих позиций рассматриваемые глаголы не являются ни переходными, ни исключениями.