# "Плохо слушается", падеж

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление, родительный-или-винительный

Прочитал фразу вроде "ноги  плохо слушались девушк**у**". Должно быть *девушк**и***, то есть родительный падеж?

Comment: На эту тему (о переходности и управлении глагола *слушаться*): https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431114/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb

Comment: И еще (Родительный или винительный) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422287/%d0%a0%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9

Comment: Спасибо. Только тут ещё вопрос в том, одинаково ли подходить к этому в обоих случаях.

Comment: О каких двух случаях идет речь?

Comment: Ноги/руки/пальцы плохо слушаются кого-то и один слушается другого (родителей и др.).

Comment: Вы имеете в виду одушевленный или неодушевленный предмет слушается кого-то? Думаю, нет разницы. Скорее разница в том, слушаться кого-то или чего-то ( с неодуш. — только Р. п.).

Comment: *с неодуш. — только Р. п.* — Не думаю, что это обязательно так. Говорят, например, "надо было слушаться интуицию". Вы слышали в живой речи иначе? Подозреваю, что переходный процесс будет идти до конца.

Comment: Пожалуй, гораздо чаще *слушать интуицию*.

Comment: @grizzly "Слушать интуицию", "прислушиваться  к интуиции" —  встречается. "Слушаться интуицию / интуиции" — не приходилось встречать.

Answer (score 2):

"Словарь управления" Розенталя признаёт оба варианта — и родительный, и винительный падеж, но последний помечает как разговорный. Конечно, с некоторыми словами разговорный вариант более привычен нашему слуху, но далеко не со всеми: попробуйте сказать "слушаться приказы" или "слушаться советы". Мне это не удаётся.

"Ноги слушались девушки" тоже встречается в книгах. Пяти минут тренировки достаточно, наверно, чтобы более правильный вариант перестал резать слух и начал восприниматься нормально (хотя бы наравне с разговорным).

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly! Насчёт тренировки, то к родительному падежу в моём примере мне и привыкать не надо, режет слух именно "девушку". Мне тоже не удалось бы выговорить "слушаться приказы/советы". :)) Только скажите, Вы тоже уверены (как и Niemand), что разницы между моим примером и случаями, когда кто-то кого-то слушается, нету?

Comment: Как я могу быть уверен? Я этой разницы не чувствую, хотя понимаю, о чём Вы. И мне уже проще сказать "ноги плохо слушались девушки", чем "парни всегда слушались этой девушки". На последнее я никак не могу настроиться. А Вам действительно оно кажется нормальным?

Comment: Перечитал себя и увидел, что придумал странное выражение "насчёт... то". :( Вырвалось и даже не заметил.

Comment: Не знаю... "Слушались девушку" не нравится, "девушки" — понимаю, что сейчас так редко говорят, поэтому тоже немного напрягает так сказать. :/ А вот с отрицанием я гораздо увереннее выберу родительный падеж: "парни никогда не слушались этой девушки".

Comment: *И мне уже проще сказать "ноги плохо слушались девушки", чем "парни всегда слушались этой девушки".* Да, вот такая разница мне и видится: проще сказать первое Вам, а мне сложнее первое сказать иначе (не в родительном).

Answer (score 1):

Вот примеры:

― В доме я была работница: ставила самовар, топила печь, мела полы и должна была **слушаться мать, мужа, брата, сестру** ― и не выходить из их воли. [Ф. М. Решетников. Между людьми (1864)]

Ты не рассуждай, а скажи: должна дочь слушаться **матери**? [Н. Г. Чернышевский. Что делать? (1863)]

Про всех, кто ходит с палочкой, говорят, будто они, когда маленькие были, **маму свою не слушались** и поэтому с крыши упали. [Юрий Дружков (Постников). Волшебная школа (1984)]

Руки **не слушались Леву**, но, в конце концов, разоблачился и он. [Сергей Гандлевский. НРЗБ // «Знамя», 2002]

Толик и Костя, лишенные развлечения, неохотно пошли к дому: **не слушаться мать** они опасались. [Алексей Слаповский. Синдром Феникса // «Знамя», 2006]

Можно предположить следующее. Если речь идет об одушевленных предметах, то мы фактически признаем В.п., хотя и не замечаем это: сущ. во мн. числе, а также сущ. м.р. 2 скл., а также личные местоимения имеют **одинаковые формы в Р.п. и В.п.** Необычными могут показаться только формы 1 скл. и 3 скл., но они встречаются не часто

Слушать маму, слушаться маму ― по смыслу эти выражения так похожи.

**Колебания в выборе падежа для одуш. сущ. были еще в 19 веке**, но в наше время В.п. практически закрепился в речи, он нам кажется более естественным. А вот для неодушевленных существительных используется Р.п.: слушаться приказов.

Comment: Спасибо, Ксения!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, все правильно. Если малыш слушается маму и папу, то почему ноги должны слушаться девушки?

Comment: С малышом может быть и так, и так. А в начале прошлого века сказали бы, пожалуй, только "мамы и папы". Я думаю, и в середине века этот вариант был предпочтительным. Но, независимо от этого, Вы считаете, что этот случай не отличается от примера с мамой и папой, да? Спасибо, подожду, что другие скажут.

Comment: В НКРЯ от 1880 г.: Разве ты хочешь не слушаться мамы? (Анненская. Брат и сестра.)

Comment: Ну, в 1880 году... С тех пор много чего изменилось.